# How to bend dependency lines in yFiles for Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependencies, uml

I create Class Diagram in IntelliJ via yFiles from java code. It looks good but there are lots of classes and the dependency lines are crossing all over and makes reading really hard. I can't find a way to bend the dependency lines so that they don't go over the classes. Is there a way?

If the Question is unclear. There are 50 classes and a straight line is drawn from the bottom class to the class on top, this line goes over the classes in between, is there a way to bend this line so that it doesn't get in the way?